# stripe curl command line POST

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments, payment

I am trying to use stripe curl to charge a test customer 10 USD, but it returns error that the amount is incorrect.

```
    curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges      \

   -u sk_test_qtxx1EuLIMqMwOmEw3NKxxxx:     \

   -d amount=10.00                          \

   -d currency=usd                          \

   -d card[number]=4242424242424242         \

   -d card[exp_month]=12                    \

   -d card[exp_year]=2019                   \

   -d card[cvc]=123
```

The error returned was:

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Invalid integer: 10.00",
    "param": "amount"
  }
}
```

I tried 10, it said: "Amount must be at least 50 cents".

I wonder if I missed any post variables, like some kind of tokens or keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges), the amount parameter needs to be

> A positive integer in the smallest currency unit

So for ten dollars, you need to pass `1000`.